# gradual transition of light intensity formula

Tags: lighting

Imagine I have an x value that ranges from 1-100. The light source is pointed at x=50.

From points 35 to 65 I want intensity to be 1

At the ends (ie 1 and 100), intensity should be 0

What formula should be used to model the in between values ?

Cosine ? Inverse square law ? ratio ?

Comment: What formula "should" be used depends on what you're trying to achieve. What's the situation you want the light to model?

Comment: smoothstep(0,35,x) and ( 1.0 - smoothstep(65,100,x) )